# Magento - How complicated is it to install a custom design?

Tags: css, magento, content-management-system, skinning

I am working with a client who has already purchased Magento -eCommerce CMS. I have never worked with this program and after reading over there extremely lengthy material I am not sure if I should take on the project. I am worried that this is a little outside of my skill set. I mostly do Design and Front-End Development. I have worked with Wordpress somewhat regularly without any problems, however that is extremely well documented. My understanding of actual programming is limited. Has anyone created a skin for Magento and if so, how complicated was it?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how you define complicated. Anyone with a good understand of Magento's architecture MAY actually call it intuitive. I can say that it has a significantly higher learning curve than many other packaged application in frameworks due to its shear number of features. It's extremely easy to think you done and found out from a client that there's a page you failed to style.

To better answer your question I'll tell you what you'll be facing.

CSS:

It is possibile, though difficult, to skin Magento using purely CSS. This can be made easier depending on your design.

HTML:

There are more individual templates than I'm willing to count. I want to say upwards of 40 ".phtml" files that you can edit each with an uncomfortable amount of logic to my taste (and I'm a programmer). For the most part you can manipulate the HTML within these files as you see fit with out any trouble. You probably will have trouble if you need to edit anything logic wise or that output by PHP

XML:
Magento uses xml files for what it calls layouts. These files are actually what puts the template files mentioned above together. To do some significant changes to the default layout you will have to change these.

Realizing that you referenced wordpress. Magento is SIGNIFICANTLY more difficult to skin than wordpress. Even after a very thorough understand of magento's architecture I still get hung up when changes. Magento is full of complex caches which can prevent your changes from being visible and unexpected dependencies which you can easily break if your not careful.

This is probably a horribly written answer but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That completely answered my question! That was exactly what I was looking for. It sounds like Megento is way more trouble than I am willing to tackle.